# TestComplete Object Browser/Spy not identifying an object

Tags: testcomplete

I've got an object within my application that TestComplete Object Spy/Object Browser is unable to map to.

It's a standard WPF SurfaceButton (I have several other Surface Buttons that all work just fine)

I've attached an image of the parent object. The slider bar is mapped and usable, and the dropdown box is also mapped and usable. But the "Default" button is not mapped at all.

Is there a way to "retry" object browsing/mapping to capture this button?

Comment: where is your attached image?

Comment: Maybe Object Oriented Descriptive Programming might work.... 

Comment: Oh right attached image. I guess I need to photobucket it and provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

TestComplete 12 comes with an "Image Based Action" feature within the Keyword Test functions that allows it to find things it couldn't find before. If the button can be seen on the screen, it can be clicked.

1. In the keyword test right-click and select "Insert Operation".
2. Click "Image Based Action".
3. Follow the prompts to select the image from the screen and give it a name and an image repository to store it in.
4. Specify the action to take on the image.

The action will take place at the center of the image by default.